# Do multivariate integrals take account of orientation?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Suppose a well-constructed function: are those integrals equivalents?
$$
\int_{-1}^{+1} \int_{-1}^{+1} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy \hspace{35pt} \int_{+1}^{-1} \int_{-1}^{+1} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy
$$

If they are not, then why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider here that
$$g(y)=\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x,y)\ dx$$
thus
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x,y)\ dx\ dy=\int_{-1}^{+1}g(y)\ dy$$

And OTOH you should know that
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}g(y)\ dy=-\int_{+1}^{-1}g(y)\ dy$$

Therefore
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x,y)\ dx\ dy=-\int_{-1}^{+1}\int_{+1}^{-1}f(x,y)\ dx\ dy=\\=-\int_{+1}^{-1}\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x,y)\ dx\ dy=\int_{+1}^{-1}\int_{+1}^{-1}f(x,y)\ dx\ dy$$

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

Suppose,
$$
\frac{d F(x,y)}{dy} = f(x,y).
$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{+1} \int_{-1}^{+1} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy  &= \int_{-1}^{+1} \big[ F(x,1) - F(x,-1) \big] \, dx \\[10pt]
  &= -\int_{+1}^{-1} [F(x,1) - F(x,-1)] \, dx \\[10pt]
  &= -\int_{+1}^{-1} \int_{-1}^{+1} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy. \\[10pt]
\end{align*}